# How to Implement NavigationService in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls

My Silverlight application has multiple XAML pages. For example, one displays a clock, one displays a timer. I have buttons to switch back and forth like so:

```
 private void switchRight(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = new Clock();
    }

    private void switchLeft(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Content = new Timer();
    }
```

I am trying to use the NavigationService to switch back and forth so I can have other pages running in the background rather than creating a new instance each time.

I am trying

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new uri("/Timer.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

but it doesn't seem to do anything and I can't find any good examples to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dphill/archive/2009/04/28/silverlight-navigation-part-3.aspx ,

Beside, I think you can use Threading for background processes.i.e.when you start a timer no need to show any xaml.

But for page instances you need to manage it very carefully otherwise stackoverflow :)

Depending on business rules its hard to decide navigation as being in a web browser.

We created our own Wizard (with rules). You may create your own NavigationManager. For validation I can offer http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/